# How do I port forward with my modem?

Tags: networking

I've been trying to port forward for ages, but my modem is really strange, I'll attach an image:

[image: port forward problem]

Where do I fill in the 25565 port? And what does wan port mean?
Can someone help?

Comment: What is the make and model of your modem? Please [edit] the question and add this essential information.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that this is [your post](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1297495-how-do-i-port-forward-with-my-modem/?tab=comments) on linustechtips, (since it was posted almost simultaneously) and that you've found your answer.  If not, then you can find the answer there.  However, if my guess it correct and you've solved it, you might want to close this question out to avoid wasting anyone's time looking at something you don't need help with any longer..

Answer (score 1):

The WAN port is the external port an application coming from the internet sees. The LAN port is the internal port it gets mapped to. The internal client is the internal IP address (or name, I can't see from the image what's in the menu) the port gets mapped to.

If you want your internal port 25565 to be visible as external port, you need to fill it in both into "WAN port" and "LAN port". However, it's an unusual port to have, but you haven't told us what application you want to forward, and how you know it's port 25565.

Note that if your ISP does carrier grade NAT, you can port forward until you are blue in the face, but the port won't be visible externally. You'll need to contact your ISP and get a public IP address (which usually comes with a more expensive business contract).

Comment: Sorry! I'm trying to make a minecraft server with my friends, so i don't really want to make it public.

Comment: Port forwarding will make it publicly accessible though. To mitigate you might be able to filter on the network-layer if your modem supports that.

Comment: Try to set up a VPN between you and your friends (and nobody else), then.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help, i was able to figure it out.
I didn't enable mapping and gave my friends the lan-side ip address, when i had to give them my wan-side ip adress (you can find yours here: https://www.whatsmyip.org/)
so my ip consisted of (wan-side ip here:25565)
I hope everyone who has the same problem finds this helpful!